# Error with struct linked list in Keil

Tags: c, struct, embedded, keil, 8051

I was working on a project of mine and the code I have posted below ran successfully in Dev C complete with O/P. However Keil is spitting out errors which I have unfortunately not been able to pin down.

Some samples:

> 8051TEST.C(322): warning C198: sizeof returns zero
>
> 8051TEST.C(324): error C230: 'switc': unknown struct/union/enum tag
>
> 8051TEST.C(324): error C204: 's0': undefined member
>
> 8051TEST.C(325): error C230: 'switc': unknown struct/union/enum tag
>
> 8051TEST.C(325): error C204: 's1': undefined member
>
> 8051TEST.C(326): error C230: 'switc': unknown struct/union/enum tag

Would really like a fresh pair of eyes.

Thanks,
Aurelius

```
 typedef struct
 {
 int s0;
 int s1;
 int s2;
 int s3;
 int c;
 int name_len;
 int struct_size;
 char sw_name[10]; //variable length array must be last.
 }switc;

 //Memory allocation and initialisation of structure
 struct switc *createsw(struct switc *s, int id1, int id2, int id3, int id4, 
 int id5, char a[])
 {
s = malloc( sizeof(*s) + sizeof(char) * strlen(a) );

s->s0 = id1;
s->s1 = id2;
s->s2 = id3;
s->s3 = id4;
s->c = id5;
s->name_len = strlen(a);
strcpy(s->sw_name, a);

s->struct_size = ( sizeof(*s) + sizeof(char) * strlen(s->sw_name) );

return s;    
}

  struct newcard //create your own configuration
    {
  int pos_sw1;
  int pos_sw2;
  int pos_sw3;
  int pos_sw4;
  int pos_sw5;
  int pos_sw6;
  int pos_sw7;
   };

 struct newcard *createcard(struct newcard *c, int sr1, int sr2, int sr3, 
 int sr4, int sr5, int sr6, int sr7)
 {
c = malloc( sizeof(*c));

c->pos_sw1 = sr1;
c->pos_sw2 = sr2;
c->pos_sw3 = sr3;
c->pos_sw4 = sr4;
c->pos_sw5 = sr5;
c->pos_sw6 = sr6;
c->pos_sw7 = sr7;
return c;    
}
```

My int main() as requested. Bit of a mish mash so apologise in advance. The whole thing worked flawlessly in Dev C.

```
  int main()
{
Lcd4_Init();
Lcd4_Clear();
switc *s1, *s2, *s3, *s4, *s5, *s6 , *s7;
int id1[5],id2[5],id3[5],id4[5],id5[5],id6[5],id7[5],pos=3;
int cd1[7],cd2[7],cd3[7],cd4[7],cd5[7],cd6[7],sw1=0,sw2=0,sw3=0,sw4=0,sw5=0,
sw6=0,s
  w7=0,card=0,menu=0,n=7;
  int *cd7=(int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));

M:menu=main_menu();

if(menu==1)//menu to monitor functions
{
 confsel();
 goto M;    
}

//assign number to card based on option selected.
if(menu==2){
card=cardsel();
}

if(menu==3)//Mini info guide 
{
 printf("\nPCB for 6x8 through(SW 1,2,3,4,5,7) + 1x11 through(SW 6) ROTARY SWITCH(s).\n");
 printf("\nSwitch LAYER(s) by 1:8 and 1:16 DEMUX.\n");
 printf("\nTRIGGER to DEMUX(s) by 8255A-5 PPI.\n");
 printf("\nAT89C51RD2 powering device.\n");
 printf("\nEnter card when PROMPTED.\n");
 printf("\nCOOLING FAN provided.\n");
 printf("\nPOTENTIOMETER P(1-5) must be ANTI-CLOCKWISE.\n");
 goto M;    
}

switch(card)
   {
   case 1:
  printf("Power Card assigned\n");
    memcpy(cd1,&pcard,sizeof(cd1));
    sw1=cd1[0];
    sw2=cd1[1];
    sw3=cd1[2];
    sw4=cd1[3];
    sw5=cd1[4];
    sw6=cd1[5];
    sw7=cd1[6];
  break;
case 2:
  printf("Firing Card assigned\n");
    memcpy(cd2,&fcard,sizeof(cd2));
    sw1=cd2[0];
    sw2=cd2[1];
    sw3=cd2[2];
    sw4=cd2[3];
    sw5=cd2[4];
    sw6=cd2[5];
    sw7=cd2[6];
  break;
case 3:
  printf("Const. Curr. Card assigned\n");
    memcpy(cd3,&c1card,sizeof(cd3));
    sw1=cd3[0];
    sw2=cd3[1];
    sw3=cd3[2];
    sw4=cd3[3];
    sw5=cd3[4];
    sw6=cd3[5];
    sw7=cd3[6];
  break;
case 4:
  printf("Const. Curr. 2 Card assigned\n");
    memcpy(cd4,&c2card,sizeof(cd4));
    sw1=cd4[0];
    sw2=cd4[1];
    sw3=cd4[2];
    sw4=cd4[3];
    sw5=cd4[4];
    sw6=cd4[5];
    sw7=cd4[6];
  break;
case 5:
  printf("Amplifier Card assigned\n");
    memcpy(cd5,&acard,sizeof(cd5));
    sw1=cd5[0];
    sw2=cd5[1];
    sw3=cd5[2];
    sw4=cd5[3];
    sw5=cd5[4];
    sw6=cd5[5];
    sw7=cd5[6];
  break;
case 6:
  printf("NC (ATM) Card assigned\n");
    memcpy(cd6,&nccard,sizeof(cd6));
    sw1=cd6[0];
    sw2=cd6[1];
    sw3=cd6[2];
    sw4=cd6[3];
    sw5=cd6[4];
    sw6=cd6[5];
    sw7=cd6[6];
  break;
case 7:
  printf("Custom Card assigned\n");
    incdec(cd7,n);//function to extract values to cd7[] 
    struct newcard *c1;
    c1=createcard(c1,*(cd7 + 0),*(cd7 + 1),*(cd7 + 2),*(cd7 + 3),*(cd7 + 4),*(cd7 + 5),*(cd7 + 6));    
    sw1=c1->pos_sw1;
    sw2=c1->pos_sw2;
    sw3=c1->pos_sw3;
    sw4=c1->pos_sw4;
    sw5=c1->pos_sw5;
    sw6=c1->pos_sw6;
    sw7=c1->pos_sw7;
  break; 
default:
  printf("Invalid Card assigned\n");
  break;
  }
```

Menu subroutines on demand.

```
   int main_menu()
  {
const char Main_Menu [3][11] = 
  {
        "1.CONFIG",//TBD
        "2.LOAD",//load PRELOADED_CARD or create CUSTOM_CARD 
        "3.INFO"//check temp/voltage/credits
  };
int menu=0,j=0,i=0;
Lcd4_Set_Cursor(1,3);
M:Lcd4_Write_String("Select your option:");
Lcd4_Set_Cursor(2,4);
Lcd4_Write_String(Main_Menu[j]);

do{
if(RK==0&&j<3)//Right Key
 {
j++;
if(j>=0||j<3)
 {
Lcd4_Set_Cursor(2,4);
Lcd4_Write_String(Main_Menu[j]);
 }
 }

if(LK==0&&j>0)//Left Key
 {
 j--;
 if(j>=0||j<3)
  {
  Lcd4_Set_Cursor(2,4);
  Lcd4_Write_String(Main_Menu[j]);
  }
  }

 if(UK==0)//Up Key
 {
 goto M;
 }

if(EK==0)//Enter Key
 {
if(j>=0||j<3)
 {
menu=j+1;
i=1;
 }
 }

return menu;
 }while(i!=1);  
 }
```

Error messages on demand (once int main starts it all goes downhill.)

8051TEST.C(464): error C141: syntax error near 'switc'

8051TEST.C(464): error C202: 's1': undefined identifier

8051TEST.C(465): error C141: syntax error near 'int'

8051TEST.C(465): error C202: 'id1': undefined identifier

8051TEST.C(466): error C141: syntax error near 'int'

8051TEST.C(466): error C202: 'cd1': undefined identifier

8051TEST.C(467): error C141: syntax error near 'int'

8051TEST.C(467): error C202: 'cd7': undefined identifier

8051TEST.C(469): error C202: 'menu': undefined identifier

8051TEST.C(471): error C202: 'menu': undefined identifier

8051TEST.C(478): error C202: 'menu': undefined identifier

and 200 more of these C202s.

Comment: `struct switc` -> `switc`. You can't combine typedef and typing out `struct` explicitly.

Comment: Btw when posting code on SO make sure to properly format and indent it. This code is quite unreadble.

Comment: Sorry for the mess but the main program is quite expansive.

Comment: Either your main() program is properly indented or it is not, no matter how long it is.

Comment: Stop passing in arguments that are not used, and just overwritten immediately. Just use a local variable instead.

Comment: What is this `M:menu` thing you are using? Doesn't really look like C.

Comment: It's used to cycle between options in the menu.

Comment: And what is it? Some static C++ object? `M:` is no valid C syntax.

Comment: I'm using a simple goto statement to cycle between the menu. I added the main menu interface as an example.

Comment: Note that neither "Dev C" nor "Keil" are compilers.  I am not sure what "Dev C" refers to , but presumably Dev C++ which is an IDE typically used with MinGW GCC, while Keil is a company that produces development tools for a number of targets.  When specifying tools it is useful to be precise, specify the compiler rather then the IDE or the vendor,  and include version numbers.  In this case however your error is clear, and I doubt that this code truly compiled in any compiler.

Comment: Note also that the compiler messages identify the line number of the error - you could help by identifying at least the line number of the start of each fragment.

Answer (score 1):

When you `typedef` a struct you only need the name `switc` so either don't typedef it, or don't use `struct switc` for the variable/parameters.

Comment: I use switc as in      // switc *s1, *s2, *s3, *s4, *s5, *s6 , *s7; in int main but I get error regarding  error C202: 's1': undefined identifier

Comment: @aurelius I don't see your `int main()`.  Post it?

Comment: @aurelius post your code instead of describing it. Please read this: [ask] and this [mcve].

Comment: Added int main(). Sorry for the mess but main program is quite big. The microcontroller being used is p89v51rd2.

Comment: @aurelius If `main(...)` is in a different file you should define the struct in a header and include it in both files, otherwise make sure the struct is defined **BEFORE** your main function.  I usually like to put main at the bottom of the file, it logically follows.

Comment: Main is in the same file as the struct. Only the header files for LCD and microcontroller are given as separate. Problem is that Keil is refusing to acknowledge identifiers   
8051TEST.C(571): error C202: 'sw6': undefined identifier
8051TEST.C(572): error C202: 'sw7': undefined identifier                            whereas the whole thing ran in Dev C with 0 errors.

Comment: @aurelius Trust me the problem is the code, not Keil.

Comment: Using `switc` should be fine but this line is wrong: `struct switc *createsw(struct switc *s,...` as there is no `struct switc` defined.

Comment: Any insights then? I have the whole thing falling apart at the switc structure pointer nexus. Does Keil have another way of declaring linked lists?

Comment: If there is no `struct switc`, there is no `*s` defined and hence no `s->s1` etc. The error message is very precisy about that

Comment: But there is a whole structure declared with typedef struct{}switc;

Comment: @aurelius Probably you compiled the code as non-standard C++ in Dev C++, rather than as standard C? Btw Dev C++ is about as obsolete as 8051, you should get a better PC toolchain. I would recommend Codeblocks with the latest GCC/Mingw compiler.

Comment: @Lundin It definitely shows it's age but for this project the 8051 is adequate. Anyway how do I declare the switc structure such that the logic is true in int main(). I really need those *s1,*s2 for my output to my PPI.

Comment: "But there is a whole structure declared with typedef struct{}switc;" This struct does not have a name. Therefore `struct switc` is invalid.

Comment: @aurelius My comment was mostly pointing at Dev C++ being old and obsolete - it is no longer maintained. You can get Codeblocks with Mingw for free, http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/binaries. It comes with a fairly new version of GCC (which can be manually upgraded if desired) and a much better debugger than the crappy one in Dev C++.

Comment: @aurelius As for replacement to 8051, they aren't free... an ARM Cortex M0 might cost as much as $2! But unfortunately you can't use it as a bookend, as you could with 8051 DIP packages :) [This might appeal to through-hole fans though](https://www.nxp.com/products/microcontrollers-and-processors/arm-based-processors-and-mcus/lpc-cortex-m-mcus/lpc1100-cortex-m0-plus-m0/scalable-entry-level-32-bit-microcontroller-mcu-based-on-arm-cortex-m0-plus-m0-cores:LPC1114FN28).

Comment: I used GCC. Better than Keil and free as well wrt 64k.

Comment: @aurelius Dev C++ uses a very outdated version of GCC, somewhere between 10 to 15 years old.

Comment: @Lundin So a little doubt here. I did as asked but I'm still getting a syntax error in int main(). Any suggestions? Switc is not being linked to the Typedef Struct.

Answer (score 0):

Basically cleblanc's answer mentions it, but I want to make it a bit more clear.

The definition of the struct and the typedef is not used correctly:

What you use:

```
typedef struct /* IMPORTANT: NO TAG HERE! */
{
 int s0;
 int s1;
 ...
} switc;
```

Defined types: `switc`

Valid usage:

```
switc *s1, *s2, *s3, *s4, *s5, *s6 , *s7;
s1->s1 = ...;
```

Invalid usage:

```
struct switc *s;
s->s1 = ...;
```

---

What you think you are using:

```
typedef struct switc /* NOTE: STRUCT WITH TAG. */
{
 int s0;
 int s1;
 ...
} switc;
```

Defined types: `struct switc` and `switc`

Valid usage:

```
switc *s1, *s2, *s3, *s4, *s5, *s6 , *s7;
s1->s1 = ...;
struct switc *s;
s->s1 = ...;
```

EDIT:

For your main function the situation is different. Here the compiler does not complain about unknown type `switch`. Instead the compiler is unhappy with your function body.

```
int main()
{
  Lcd4_Init();
  Lcd4_Clear();
  switc *s1, *s2, *s3, *s4, *s5, *s6 , *s7;
```

Prior to C99 standard, it was mandatory to put all variable definitions at the top of the function body. Is it was mentioned in some comments that Keil Dev C is rather old style, I would expect that it only supports K&R and C89.
(Last time I used a Keil C compiler for C16x was in 2006. At that time no C99 support was available.)

You are violating this rule by calling some `LCD4_...` functions first.
As no variable definitions are allowed afterwards, no type name is allowed as well.

To fix it, simply change your order of lines:

```
int main()
{
  switc *s1, *s2, *s3, *s4, *s5, *s6 , *s7;
  Lcd4_Init();
  Lcd4_Clear();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying. One teeny tiny doubt. I'm still getting these errors wrt switc in int main() even after valid use. 8051TEST.C(463): error C141: syntax error near 'switc' 8051TEST.C(463): error C202: 's1': undefined identifier 8051TEST.C(464): error C141: syntax error near 'int' 8051TEST.C(464): error C202: 'id1': undefined identifier 8051TEST.C(465): error C141: syntax error near 'int'

Comment: Is `main()` defined in the same file as `switc` or are those 2 snippets from different files?

Comment: the main_menu() is a menu function

Comment: I was asking about `main` where you get the syntax error messages.

Comment: Yup int main() is where the main program run time starts.

Comment: In which way could this possible answer my question? WHERE is it defined? Same file or another file?

Comment: same file. int main()

Comment: Please show the exact error messages and show to which lines in your snippet they relate.

Comment: Wait.... Same file as `main_menu` or same file as definition of `switc` ?

Comment: There is one file only 8051test or whatever. Thw switc is a separate structure and the main menu simply calls based on the const char list it has.

Comment: Main menu goto boondongle simply allows you to cycle between menus.

Comment: M: is simply a goto statement to trigger the main_menu() function. Errors start at the switc *s1,*s2..... line in snippet #2. Basically the compiler is not recognizing the typedef struct ... switc with switc *s1,*s2.

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: @aurelius OMG! I am sorry, I was somehow blind. What C standard is supported? C89 does not allow variable definitions after other statements. Move the calls to `Lcd4_*` after the definitions. Does your code really have a line break within `s w7`?

Comment: And I was also a bit blinded by the label.  Confused it with :: from C++. Sorry for that

Comment: @aurelius any improvement?